# Should closed questions be included in the related links on the right?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, links

I noticed that in the links to related question on the lower right hand side of the page when viewing a question  that the list contain links to closed questions, without metioning that they are closed in the link.

This doesn't make any sense to me.  Why would we want to link to closed questions?  At least they should say they are closed questions in the link title by including the `[Closed]` bit in the link title surely?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

By dint of the body, tag, and title matching, those questions *are* related. So if you have a lot of [closed] questions related to that one, it's symptomatic of a problem with the question itself.

Also, remember that closed questions may point to a merge, and are still useful signposts to other questions.

Comment: Then wouldn't it make sense to have the [closed] visible in the link on the right, so you might see that a lot of similar questions have been closed, and so be aware of the symptomatic problem with the question.

Comment: We could make a practice of appending the titles with (closed) by hand, so it shows up in the Related list.

Comment: @Ocaasi: that sounds like just a crazy amount of work for something that could be done by the site.

Comment: absolutely @Knives. My guess is that Ocaasi didn't come here from Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I just got annoyed but this StackExchange bug, so I'm posting an answer to revive this as an issue.

Is there somewhere useful we can report StackExchange bugs?

Comment: The meta is the place to report SE bugs. In this case, it was closed by a member of the SE team (who happens to be a founder) as "status by design". Even if you are annoyed by it, I don't think that a discussion elsewhere can help you if the team is against changing it. Or did I misunderstand your post?